# How can I duplicate adjacency lists without breaking parent-child relationships?

Tags: postgresql, query, hierarchy

I would like to duplicate hierarchical structures, modelled as adjacency lists, in my database.

The following tables and records allow a minimal reproduction:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_groups (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL
);
  
CREATE TABLE items (
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id uuid REFERENCES items(id),
  group_id serial NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO item_groups VALUES
  (1, 'Group 1');

INSERT INTO items VALUES
  ('1c22001d-a2fa-412f-bc6d-b9ae10a717ba', NULL, 1),
  ('0b41df47-07b2-48af-b70f-b3dc73dacba3', '1c22001d-a2fa-412f-bc6d-b9ae10a717ba', 1),
  ('d4e6c9e2-f08d-4c6a-8790-056d31d96165', NULL, 1),
  ('47193aa5-6fcd-44ad-b37d-91e4515dcaf7', 'd4e6c9e2-f08d-4c6a-8790-056d31d96165', 1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/bFd6wrL2

**How can I duplicate 'items' pertaining to 'Group 1' while maintaining the parent-child relationship?**

In my naivety, I tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO items (id, parent_id, group_id)
SELECT
  gen_random_uuid() AS id,
  parent_id,
  group_id
FROM items
WHERE group_id = 1
```

But this breaks the parent-child relationship of the new records (because only `id` has been updated). I would like the new children to reference the new parents (not the old).